# ngOninit in component is not loading in navigation angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I am calling `this.router.navigate(['detailscomponent']);` but i am unable to call ngOninit of a component

I tried the below method in which is working fine but i have to create a dummy component as shown below

```
 let url:any='/valuation';
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dummy', { skipLocationChange: true });
    setTimeout(() =>this.router.navigate([url,abc]));
```

Is there any other method to load oninit component in ts ?

Comment: Please try to better explain what exactly are you doing? from what route are you navigating from?

Comment: @Ron So basically i have a parent page where 2 child components are getting called. So there is a side bar menu in all the pages. So when i click on the side bar menu link then the oninit for both the child component is not called. I want both to be called. Could you tell me how to do that.the above code works but i have to put a dummy component. So basically i dont want to use this dummy component, I want to know if there is any better way to this.

Comment: so you basically want some code to happen onRouting but do not need the actual component? Why would you use onInit in that case at all? Or routing for that matter?

Comment: @Chund i need the actual component as well. basically i want all the components to be reloaded when i click anything from sidebar menu

Comment: @harshamullangi you should reconsider your components architecture, there is no reasonable scenario that you should rerender **all** your child components..

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of solutions here:

all solutions require that you will add to your router config onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'

```js
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

### change Router's [routeReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#routeReuseStrategy)

this will change the loading behaviour globally and for all routes and will **actually** rerender the component (which will trigger ngOnInit)

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy = () => false;
}
```

### listen to router events in the components that should reload

```js
export class ReloadableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 private destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject();     

 constructor(private router: Router) {
   // subscribe to the router events.
   this.router.events.pipe(
       takeUntil(this.destroy$),
       // If it is a NavigationEnd event re-init the component
       filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
     ).subscribe((e: any) => {
       this.refresh();
   });
 }

 refresh() {
   // Set default values and re-fetch any data you need.
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  // will be called only once
  this.refresh();
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
   // emit a value which will unsubscribe from all observables.
   this.destroy$.next();
 }
}
```

### move logic that should be reloaded to guards and resolvers

and then just set runGuardsAndResolvers to 'always' for the components that should reload

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'reloadable',
   component: ParentComponent,
   runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
   resolve: { data: DataResolver }
 }
]
```

**Note**: runGuardsAndResolvers affect all children's guards and resolvers as well

Comment: I had one specific URI that I needed to rerun the ngOnInit on every page change and not reuse the original component. I used your first option but had to modify it to 

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
        this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function() { return false; };
}`
I am super new to Angular so I am not sure why I had to modify it to the above.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer to your problem is listed below. `{onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’}` will reload your current component if you are hitting again.

```
@ngModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})],
   exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Happy to help.